# is there exist some alternative of Enum.GetName(Type, Object) method in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

in c# is possible to get enum name of any type with method

```
Enum.GetName (Type, Object)
```

is there possible to do the same in Swift?

As example I have some enum that must have **Int** raw value, but also I need it's own name. 
how to do this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-requisite: you have an enumeration type with an underlying `RawValue`; i.e., an enumeration conforming to [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rawrepresentable).

---

The C# method [Enum.GetName Method (Type, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname) is described as follows:

> **`Enum.GetName Method (Type, Object)`**
>
> ```
> public static string GetName(
>   Type enumType,
>   object value
> )
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> *`enumType`*
>
> - Type: `System.Type`
> - An enumeration type.
>
> *`value`*
>
> - Type: `System.Object`
> - The value of a particular enumerated constant *in terms of its underlying type*.
>
> Return Value
>   - Type: `System.String`
>   - A string containing the name of the enumerated constant in `enumType` whose value is `value`; or `null` if no such constant is
>   found.

*"Translated"* into Swift, this method takes an `enum` *type* as first argument, and a *value of the underlying type* of the enum as its second one; where the latter would (for the pre-requisites of `RawRepresentable` conformance) translate into a *value of the `RawValue` type of the enum* in Swift.

Finally, the return type `System.String` (with possible `null` return) would translate to an optional `String` return type in Swift (`String?`).

Knitting these observations together, you could implement your similar `getName` method (for finding `String` representation of your cases represented as `YourEnum.RawValue` instances at runtime) by combining the `init?(rawValue:)` blueprinted in `RawRepresentable` with the `init(describing:)` initializer of `String`:

```
func getName<T: RawRepresentable>(_ _: T.Type, rawValue: T.RawValue) -> String? {
    if let enumCase = T(rawValue: rawValue) {
        return String(describing: enumCase)
    }
    return nil
}

/* example setup */
enum Rank: Int {
    case n2 = 2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,J,Q,K,A
}

/* example usage */
let someRawValue = 7
if let caseName = getName(Rank.self, rawValue: someRawValue) {
    print(caseName) // n7
}
```

---

This is contrived and coerced "translation" however, as Swift `enum`:s are quite different (and more powerful) than those of C#. You would generally have an actual instance instance of the enum (e.g. `Rank.n7`) rather than one of its `RawValue` (e.g. `7`), in which case you could simply use the `init(describing:)` initializer of `String` directly as described in [the answer of @AlexanderMomchliov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411958/4573247).

Comment: This is a more direct copy of the C# API, but I don't think we should be encouraging writing C# in Swift

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Agreed!

Answer (score 1):

To get an enumeration case's name as a `String`, you can use `init(describing:)` on `String`:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}

let s = String(describing: Foo.A)
print(s) // "A"
```

You can bake this into the enum:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case A
    case B
    case C
    var asString: String { return String(describing: self) }
}

let s = Foo.A.asString
print(s) // "A"
```

Comment: I believe your initial answer answered the question, whereas this edit, does not. The C# method `Enum.GetName(Type, Object)` uses an enum type and _an object_, the latter argument described as _"The **value** of a particular enumerated constant **in terms of its underlying type**."_. You current answer only makes use of a given _type and case (typed @ compile time)_ (e.g. `Foo.A`) to prints itself. I believe what the OP is looking for is printing a description (runtime) of the case given a type and a `rawValue` (i.e., given an instance of the underlying type: here, `Int` specifically).

Comment: @dfri I know, It's throwing me off. I thought OP wanted to go from `rawValue` to `enum` case, beached of the C# he quoted. However, from his own attempt at an answer,I found out he's actually trying to go from enum case to `String`.

Comment: @dfri Actually, I just looked it up, our ideas about the semantics of the provided C# is wrong. It obtains the enum case as a String.

Comment: In his own attempt he's trying to go from _instance of_ enum case to `String` (usable at runtime): the current answer only shows how to go from type enum and case _type_ to `String` (which can only be used, as is, for statements specified at compile time). W.r.t. C4 version: yes, it obtains enum case as `String` given what we would refer to as its rawvalue in Swift (given a value "underlying type").

Comment: Actually this is correct enought answer for me, Thanks a lot, Alexander Momchilliov!

Comment: @Andrew just note that the C# version uses _instances_ of an enumeration to get its "description" as a `System.String`, whereas the solution above uses a given _typed case_ (not an instance!), e.g. `Foo.A` to get a `String` instance describing that type case. (However the solution above, the `String` initializer `init(describing:)` can naturally be applied to enum case _instances_ I'm just pointing out that it is not used that way here).

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov also noted you have a downvote (for some reason: revenge downvote from the other downvoted answer? :P), just want to point out that you have +1 from me :) (you posted the appropriate method `String(describing:)`, just, imo, not used in exactly the context as the C3 method queried about, but apples and oranges!).

Comment: @dfri It was likely a revenge down vote. I don't mind :p